# Error redirecting non-www to https

Tags: http, ssl, nginx, https

i wanna redirect al to https://example.com
This redirections works fine:

```
http://www.example.com -> https://example.com
https://www.example.com -> https://example.com
```

but this dont work:

```
http://example.com -> https://example.com
```

this is my nginx complete config:

```
server {
        server_name www.example.com;
        return 301 https://example.com$request_uri;
}

server {
        listen   80; ## listen for ipv4; this line is default and implied
        listen   [::]:80 default_server ipv6only=on; ## listen for ipv6

        root /var/www/laravel/public;
        index index.php index.html index.htm;

        server_name example.com;

        location / {
                try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$query_string;
        }

        location /doc/ {
                alias /usr/share/doc/;
                autoindex on;
                allow 127.0.0.1;
                allow ::1;
                deny all;
        }

        error_page 404 /404.html;
        error_page 500 502 503 504 /50x.html;
        location = /50x.html {
                root /usr/share/nginx/www;
        }

        location ~ \.php$ {
            try_files $uri /index.php =404;
            fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;
            fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php5-fpm.sock;
            fastcgi_index index.php;
            fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
            include fastcgi_params;
        }
}

server {
        listen 443 ssl;

        server_name example.com;
        add_header Strict-Transport-Security "max-age=31536000";

        ssl_certificate /home/user/example.com.chained.crt;
        ssl_certificate_key /home/user/example.com.key;
}
```

i see a lot of example to redirect that but the server goes to the error 500 and too many redirections.

Answer (score 0):

Add example.com to server_name

Hope that helps.